# Need date picker for R application

Tags: r, datepicker

I am searching for a simple date picker to use with R. I can find many pickers written in other languages, but I would rather not mix languages if at all possible. Does anyone know of a R package which provides this functionality?

Comment: Would you give a link to a date picker in another language

Comment: @csgillespie - I've used the jQueryUI datepicker before with good results: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Comment: I can't get `RGtk2` to install properly on my system, but `GtkCalendar` should provide what you are looking for.

Comment: James if you are on windows, you will likely just need to uninstall the Gtk libraries, then install RGtk2 and let it prompt you to install the libraries. It might also be a conflict with XML.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind installing gWidgets and gWidgetstcltk you have this:

```
library(gWidgetstcltk)
options(guiToolkit="tcltk")
#    
pickDate <- function() {
  date <- NULL
  dlg <- gbasicdialog(handler=function(...) date <<- svalue(calendar))
  calendar <- gcalendar(cont=dlg)
  visible(dlg, set=TRUE)
  date
}
```

Comment: Although this gives me a nice dialog box with today's date pre-populated, I am looking for what would be in VB a "calendar" control. This is not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: this library does not exist anymore, there is a 2nd version that crashes the R Studio when I try to install the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use gcalendar() from gWidgets.

```
options("guiToolkit"="RGtk2")
library(RGtk2)
library(gWidgets)

win <- gwindow("Test Calendar", width=12)   
Group <- ggroup(cont=win)

tmp <- gframe("Date", container=Group )
add(tmp, calStart)
add(tmp, calEnd)

calStart <- gcalendar("Debut", format = "%Y-%m-%d")
calEnd <- gcalendar("Fin", format = "%Y-%m-%d")

dateStart <- svalue(calStart) 
dateFin <- svalue(calEnd)
```

Perhaps, this can help you.

Regards,

YougyZ